# How to avoid needing to supply template twice in constructor of class?

Tags: c++

I have the following two classes:

```
template<std::size_t Num>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const std::array<int,Num>& nums)
    :
        m_nums(nums){}

protected:
    const std::array<int,Num>& m_nums;
};

template<typename... Foos>
class Bar
{
public:

    Bar(Foos... foos)
    :
        m_foos(std::make_tuple(foos...))
    {

    }

protected:
    std::tuple<Foos...> m_foos;
};
```

That I would use like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int,2> nums1 = {0,1};
    std::array<int,1> nums2 = {0};

    Bar<Foo<2>,Foo<1>> bar(Foo<2>(nums1), Foo<1>(nums2));

    return 0;
}
```

How can I avoid the need to specify `Foo<2>` and `Foo<1>` twice? I tried `Bar<> bar(Foo<2>(nums1), Foo<1>(nums2));` but that didn't compile.

Comment: You probably want to write some deduction guides. Then you wouldn't need to specify any template arguments, not even for the class itself.

Comment: @GézaTörök The implicit deduction guides work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CTAD, the implicit deduction guides already have you covered:

```
Bar bar{Foo<2>(nums1), Foo<1>(nums2)};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6g1fkf

(Note that you run into the most vexing parse here if you use parentheses instead of curly braces.)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor can just forward the arguments:

```
Bar(Foos... foos)
    : m_foos(std::move(foos)...)
{}
```

And then:

```
Bar<Foo<2>,Foo<1>> bar(nums1, nums2);
```

Comment: This relies on the implicit conversion from `std::array` to `Foo` to be clear. If the `Foo` constructor were `explicit` (as some would argue it should be) this would not work. But for the given code this is indeed a solution!

Comment: @MaxLanghof Correct.

Comment: Hey I marked the other answer correct but this one is good too. Thanks.